# POST запрос Retrofit 2.0, ошибка при при преобразовании данных в gson

Tags: android, retrofit, gson, яндекс-переводчик

Пытаюсь подключиться к API Яндекс.Переводчика.
При преобразовании `response` с помощью `gson` в строке:

```
mapGetResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), Map.class);
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:  
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException:  
Unterminated array at line 1 column 35 path $.[1]
```

Причем это происходит, только если возвращается перевод из более, чем одного слова. Если переводить только одно слово, то все нормально.

`MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final String URL = "https://translate.yandex.net";
    public final String KEY = "trnsl.1.1.20160324T093729Z.b14b7c54accb1f8e.7d811d65e5f9b19b5541568a35af1e6c8019b10e";

    private TextView tvTranslate;
    private EditText etInputText;
    private Gson gson;
    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private YandexTranslateService service;
    private Map<String, String> mapJson, mapGetResponse;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvTranslate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTranslate);
        etInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInputText);

        gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(URL)
                .build();

        service = retrofit.create(YandexTranslateService.class);
    }

    public void onClickTranslate(View view) {
        mapJson = new HashMap<>();
        mapJson.put("key", KEY);
        mapJson.put("text", etInputText.getText().toString());
        mapJson.put("lang", "en-ru");

        ResponseTask responseTask = new ResponseTask();
        responseTask.execute();

        try {
            Response<Object> response = responseTask.get();
            System.out.println(response.body());
            mapGetResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), Map.class);
            System.out.println(mapGetResponse);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (Map.Entry e: mapGetResponse.entrySet()){
            if (e.getKey().equals("text")) {
                tvTranslate.setText(e.getValue().toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public void onClickClear(View view){
        tvTranslate.setText("");
        etInputText.setText("");
    }

    class ResponseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Response<Object>>{
        Response<Object> response;
        @Override
        protected Response<Object> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Call<Object> call = service.translate(mapJson);
            try {
                response = call.execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

`YandexTranslateService`:

```
public interface YandexTranslateService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate")
    Call<Object> translate(@FieldMap Map<String, String> map);
}
```

Код ошибки:

```
03-25 06:33:05.026 19719-19719/com.gotb.testretrofit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 
         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated array at line 1 column 35 path $.[1]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:894)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:844)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:793)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:765)
        at com.gotb.testretrofit.MainActivity.onClickTranslate(MainActivity.java:65)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated array at line 1 column 35 path $.[1]
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1567)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:480)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:418)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.read(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:60)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:879)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:844) 
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:793) 
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:765) 
     at com.gotb.testretrofit.MainActivity.onClickTranslate(MainActivity.java:65) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Добавьте  json  ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Небольшая работа над ошибками.

1) retrofit запросы выполняются в отдельном потоке. вам не нужен AsyncTask.

```
service.translate(mapJson).enqueue(new Callback<TranslateData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TranslateData> call, Response<TranslateData> response) {
               TranslateData data = response.body();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TranslateData> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

2) Создайте класс для сериализации (пример приведен на основе вашего ответа)

```
public class TranslateData {
    private int code;
    private String lang;
    private ArrayList<String> text;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(String lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(ArrayList<String> text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

3) Обновите интерфейс `YandexTranslateService`.

```
Call<TranslateData> translate(@FieldMap Map<String, String> map);
```

4) Обновите код как в пункте 1.

После того как получите ответ от сервер у Вас **уже** будет готовый сериализованный ответ и не нужно будет сериализовать объект  `mapGetResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), Map.class);`

Вы уже добавили сериализатор в retrofit `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))`.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что значит "Скиньте ответ Json в двух вариантах". 

     service.translate(mapJson).enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
            Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Object> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                mapGetResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), Map.class);
            }

            Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            }
        });
responce - это же Json ответ, так?

За замечание про отдельный поток retrofit, отдельное спасибо.

Comment: Json - это то, что вы получаете до того, как сериализуете в обьект.

Comment: просто пример ответа от сервера, то что у вас в response.body()

Comment: {code=200.0, lang=en-ru, text=[я]}

Comment: я так понимаю это {"code":200.0, "lang":"en-ru", "text":[я]}

Comment: {"code":200.0,"lang":"en-ru","text":["я"]}  - вот так

Comment: обновил ответ, с вас галочка ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), Map.class);
```

У меня была ошибка 27.

В `response.body().toString()` в поле были строковые поля из нескольких слов. Пришлось добавлять дополнительные скобки при формировании `json` на сервере.

Когда в `response.body().toString()` приходил `{message:"no data"}` - это вызывал ошибку преобразования.

`{message:"'no data'"}` - не вызывал ошибки.